# Issue regarding update trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2012

I am creating a trigger for after update on table.

The table contains c1, c2, c3, c4 columns and these columns c1, c2, c3, c4 are independent of each other

Trigger was supposed to be "if an update happens on c4 column.. the trigger should be invoked and the values in c1 column should be retrieved and modified"

How can we handle this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the trigger will always be invoked, you may have to write code so that it only does something after checking to see if col 4 changed. BTW what code do you have? WE are not going to help you cheat on your homework.

Comment: HLGEM --it's not a homework :)

Comment: @user3534342 All the more reason for you to put more effort in your question

Comment: How remarkably similar this question is to the example given in the COLUMNS_UPDATED() MSDN article. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.  The UPDATE is kind of a tricky little feature but provides quick access to what you are asking for.

```
UPDATE UT
    SET
        UT.C1 = CASE WHEN UPDATE(C4) THEN I.C4 ELSE UT.C1 END
FROM
    UnderlyingTable AS UT
    INNER JOIN inserted AS I ON (UT.PrimaryKey = I.PrimaryKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AFTER/INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`.

Compare the `INSERTED` table to the `DELETED` table to see which columns were updated, and then do your logic.

You can also use `Column_Updated(columnName)` but this may have an issue with updating a record to the same value.

For more information:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Columns_Updated(columnName)` to check if a column value is changed or not, also there are two tables `inserted` and `deleted` in update trigger you can query new value from inserted and oldvalue from deleted